# Use PostSharp to Generate a Type

Tags: postsharp

We are currently using PostSharp for its standard functionality (logging, caching, transactions, and so on).

We also generate dynamically, at *runtime*, some custom classes, using Reflection.Emit. This obviously slows startup, and as we need to add more dynamic type generation, I am wondering, since all the information for the dynamic types is known at build time, whether we can use PostSharp to do this.

So, the question itself is, can I use PostSharp to achieve what I can do with Reflection.Emit, but at build time?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

The PostSharp itself is using PostSharp.Sdk to manipulate the binary code, but this API is not publicly documented and supported at the moment. So, it's not future-proof to rely on it in your project.

The closest you can get with the documented API is probably by introducing interfaces, methods and properties: http://doc.postsharp.net/content/code-injections

Comment: Yeah, I use PostSharp for introductions quite heavily already. It's creating the types that blocks me. I'll take a look at the Postsharp SDK, any samples anywhere?